# replace br tag from a string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string. I want to replace the line break with /n

```
Good FRIENDS are hard to find,<br
            /> harder to leave,<br
            /> and impossible to forget.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yeah i tried with the following example..$str = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $str); but its not wrkng

Comment: Is the linebreak in your example between `<br` and `/>` intended?

Comment: you appear to have he parameters in your example backwards.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/<br\W*?\/?>/", "\n", $string);
```

Comment: The `/` should be optionalized. Not every input will be pseudo-xhtml.

Comment: mario is right, especially today it is most likely just `<br>` instead of `<br/>`. Change the code to this to handle this as well: `preg_replace("/<br\W*?\/?>/", "\n", $your_string);`

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
str_replace("<br />", "\n", $your_string);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$text = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $text);
```

If there is actually a line break within the `<br />` tag as in your sample code, try this:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<br\n\W*\/>/", "\n", $text);
```

Comment: Neither does yours - at least on my system, \n is not covered by \W. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use This function

```
   function separate( $str,$subStr, $count )
  {
     $formatStr = '';
     $start=0;
     $num = 1;
     while(!(strpos($str,$subStr,$start) === null))
     { 
       $first = strpos($str,$subStr,$start);
       if ($first < $start)
          break; 
       $newStr = substr($str,$start,$first - $start + 1 );
       $formatStr .= $newStr;
       if ($num % $count == 0)
          $formatStr .= '<br>';
       $num ++;
       $start = $first +1;
     }
     return $formatStr;
  }
```

Example

```
$str = 'AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD.EEE.FFF.CCC';
echo separate ($str,'.', 3);
```

Output

```
AAA.BBB.CCC.
DDD.EEE.FFF.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below regex:

```
$string = preg_replace( '@^(<br\\b[^>]*/?>)+@i', '', $string );
```