# Remove <br /> from inside <pre> </pre> tag

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

I made simple BBCode script and it works all fine. But then later i use a javascript library to beautify my codes in `<pre></pre>`.

Now the only problem I am facing that I have `<br />` tags after each line of code in `<pre></pre>` tags.

So the question is how could I remove the `<br />` tags which **ARE INSIDE** the `<pre></pre>` tags only.

A regex with preg_replace seems to be the thing i need but I could not find/make one to match my need. I not much good with regex. :S

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5849130/3933332 <- See

Comment: @Rizier123 isn't that replace <br /> from all of the whole string. I want to just replace those <br /> which are inside <pre></pre>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could u provide us an example of the code u want to test please.

Pattern should looks like : `'/.*<pre>.*(<br \/>).*<\/pre>/'`

Here is the link of my try :
https://regex101.com/r/pV2qX8/2

NOTE : u can reverse the capturing braces - It was just to show u it catched only the `<br />` inside `<pre></pre>`.

NOTE 2  : 
About sub-question u can find the answer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581985/remove-multiple-instances-of-br-tag-with-condition)

(Sub-Q : multiple `<br />` instances with condition)

Comment: if you have a little more time, it does't match the second `<br />` when its between the new line  ( its in <pre> tag )

Comment: We need help :'(. I'm just a regex padawan. Can't find a solution about the greedy quantifiers. https://regex101.com/r/pV2qX8/5

Comment: haha me too. May be i will just post a new question to match this newline thing. Thanks alot for a try btw :)

Comment: non greedy quantifiers for any characters is .*? but it seems i can't use on the group  pattern.

Comment: I got it to match the new line <br /> but now it doesn't match the inline br https://regex101.com/r/pV2qX8/7

Comment: I made a full example of possible output - https://regex101.com/r/pV2qX8/8
I'm sure they'll have fun to do it - U should remake a posT.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pV2qX8/10 Updated - the pbm is still here for multiple <br />. Can't get a lazy quantifiers on () expression so it matches everytime the last <br />

Comment: Told ya monsters will solved it - 1min - It was done - Kappa : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581985/remove-multiple-instances-of-br-tag-with-condition