# Remove multiple instances of <br> tag with condition

Tags: regex

As i told in the post i'm just a regex padawan.

All started in this thread :
[Stackoverflow : remove br from inside pre tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577912/remove-br-from-inside-pre-pre-tag/30578124#30578124)

> Question was to find : `<br />` tags inside `<pre></pre>`

I made this pattern : `.*?<pre>.*\s?((<br\s*?\/?>\s?).*?){1,}<\/pre>`

I answered the question.

Everything was fine since sub-question came :

**SUB-Question : How to find ANY `<br />` inside the `<pre>` tag ?**

I Translated that in : **How to find multiples instances a of word with condition**

Explanation of my regex:

- `.*?` -  Non-greedy quantifier : any number of any characters
- `<pre>` - Followed by the tag
- `.*\s?` - any number of any char + possible whitespace character
- `(<br\s*?\/?>\s?)` - Follow by the tag we search + possible whitespace character
- **THEREFORE** `((<br \/>\s?).*?){1,}` should (match `<br />` + possible whitespace char + any number of any char) 1 or unlimited times.
  I also tried to replace {1,} by *? (since {1,} seems to be greedy) - same result.

Don't have another idea to implement this part & it doesn't work.

Regex101 : [MY attempt](https://regex101.com/r/pV2qX8/13)

It's more to improve my knowledge than gettin the result.
Hope you'll understand what i'm trying to do.

Best regard,

Falt

P.S. : i know `(<br\s*?\/?>)` find all occurencies of `<br /> tags` in the strings with option gm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<br\s*\/>(?=(?:(?!<\/?pre>)[\s\S])*<\/pre>)
```

See [DEMO and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pV2qX8/14)

**Logic:** Match all `br` tags which are followed by `</pre>` and there is no `<pre>` or `</pre>` in between.

Comment: Wow - So great - I accept when the 2 minutes countdown is done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think i got it - Thanks again - Learned something great today.