# PHP Removing <br> from echo

Tags: php, html

I am trying to stop the html br command from apearing in this code as some product titles have a br tag in the title:

```
<input id="product" name="product"  type="text" value="<?php echo $products_name ?>" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Where is the br tag?

Comment: Not a very bright question, Could be duplicate of  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849130/replace-br-tag-from-a-string-in-php]

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use [str_replace()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

```
<input id="product" name="product"  type="text" value="<?php echo str_replace("<br/>", "", $products_name) ?>"  class="form-control">
```

Comment: Yes, but he wants to remove `<br>`, not `<br/>`

Comment: To decode the questions made by newby users in SO is an art.

Comment: Ok, but show this the correct form is <br/> in XHTML (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<br>` is inside the `$products_name` variable, you can simply use the [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) function on it, like:

```
value="<?php echo strip_tags($products_name); ?>"
```

This also disallows any other HTML in the title, but that would make much sense in this context anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<input id="product" name="product"  type="text" value="<?php echo strip_tags($products_name) ?>"  class="form-control">
```

That would remove *all* HTML tags from the products_name, which I think would generally be a good idea if you're not sure if there will be any tags present ;)

Comment: But maybe he wants to keep the format of the title, links, you name it.

Comment: HTML tags in an HTML attribute? Seems unlikely, that would break the DOM.